# gitlab ci REST base URL

Tags: rest, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I tried to update a variable for gitlab ci with

```
curl --request PUT --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $CI_TOKEN" "https://gitlab.com/mathmeier/landesrunde-nrw/api/v4/projects/1/variables/DATABASE_LIST" --form "value=$NEW_DB_LIST"
```

but my URL is obviously broken. From the description on the gitlab REST api pages, I do not understand how I construct the URL. Furthermore, I do not know what this project number or id should be.

Can anybody enlighten me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the project id from the main page of the project. Then the call would look something like this:

```
curl --request PUT --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $CI_TOKEN" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/37804337/variables/DATABASES_LIST" --form-string value=$NEW_DB_LIST
```